# Java Pass array to a method in another class

Tags: java, arrays

```
package arrays2;

public class GebruikGetallenRij {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int aantal = 5;
GetallenRij gr1 = new GetallenRij(aantal);      
GetallenRij gr2 = new GetallenRij(aantal);   

System.out.println("Geef " + aantal + " getallen in: ");
gr1.leesRij();
    
System.out.println("Geef " + aantal + " getallen in: ");
gr2.leesRij();

boolean controle = gr1.vergelijk(gr2);

if (controle) System.out.println("De 2 rijen zijn gelijk");
else System.out.println("De 2 rijen zijn NIET gelijk");
}
```

}

other class

```
package arrays2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetallenRij {
private int [] rij;

public GetallenRij (int grootte) {
    rij = new int [grootte];
    }

public void leesRij() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < rij.length;i++) {
        rij[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

public boolean vergelijk(int [] rijB) {
    boolean vgl = true;
    if (rij.length != rijB.length) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < rij.length && vgl) {
        if(rij[i] != rijB[i]) vgl = false;
        i++;
    }
    }
        
    if (vgl) return true;
    else return false;
}


    
}
```

The idea of the program is to create 2 array objects, write in values and compare them. However I can't pass the second array gr2 to the method that compares the arrays (public boolean vergelijk(int [] rijB). I get following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method vergelijk() in the type GetallenRij is not applicable for the arguments (GetallenRij) at arrays2.GebruikGetallenRij.main(GebruikGetallenRij.java:18)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: maybe you want `gr1.vergelijk(gr2.rij);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to pass a `GetallenRij` object to a method that's expecting a `int[]`, which is causing the compile error.

Change the method to accept a `GetallenRij` and assign its `rij` to a local variable `int [] rijB`, leaving the rest of your code as-is:

```
public boolean vergelijk(GetallenRij getallenRij) {
    int [] rijB = getallenRij.rij;
    // rest of code same as before
}
```

---

While you're there, change:

```
if (vgl) return true;
else return false;
```

to:

```
return vgl;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick response and good explanation.

Comment: No worries. See [What to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)